# Node Port Service routing traffic problem

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I have 2 replicas of my app with Node_Port as type of Service.

When i request my app using external worker node IP.  I have response from different pod. It's looks like round robin. I want always get response from pod only on requested worker node.

Headless service doesn't work with Node_Port type.
How i can disable this round robin?

Comment: type NodePort of service and externalTrafficPolicy: Local solve my problem

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.